# Ruby Passenger displays content from public instead of the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, web, passenger

I have a server in the cloud. I've set up a Linux machine with Apache2 + Passenger(with the apache module installed). 
I've configured by the book, set up the VirtualHost as the Passenger instructions tell me to.
I've created a default Ruby on Rails project in "RubyMine"(on the local machine), synchronized it with the server.
Here is the project file hierarchy:
[image]

Since the instructions ask me to point in the configuration file to /projectFolder/public, I did so. If there is no index.html in the public folder, it throws me an error, if I create one it displays it when I access the link.
But when on the local machine I deploy it, it instead launches the app from app->views->layouts.
How to make it run on the remote server my ruby code? My ruby "app"?

Comment: Can you please include your vhost config?

Comment: @ChrisHeald The root wasn't seeing rails. I installed on the root user too and now it works.

Comment: Correction: looked more like a RubyMine problem. When I create with rails command it works good but when I copy the files created by RubyMine it jumps to public folder which is because of an error from what I've read.

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
sudo passenger-status
```

This should show you if passenger is loaded and the applications group. If that is all good, delete the index.html from /public and restart apache.

Comment: It says Application groups: /var/www#default: App root: /var/www. That's where my project folder is. It still gives an error when I open the page.

Comment: Someone suggested on github on a similar problem that libv8-dev should be installed. I installed it and it doesn't give me an error now but it shows 404.html from the public folder.

Comment: May be I have to run the server using the "rails" command or it should work like that through apach2? May be I have to write routes(I didn't write any)?

Comment: I managed to solve my first problem by installing libv8-dev(and then also node.js). The second problem was strange a bit. I installed everything on the user I login to the server. Now I moved to the root user and installed rails and RVM and "magically" it started working. On the root it didn't have rails while on the user I was logging in it had... Interesting but it works so I guess it's good :)